# jQuery in iframe on page doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, facebook, iframe

I am having some trouble in making APPENDED jQuery work in a page on an iframe.  I either get

> Uncaught Error:

or

> Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined

The following section that is responsible for appending script to page that is displayed on iframe:

```
var simpleScriptTest = '<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js">'+
'</script>'+
'<script>'+
  '$("a").hover(function(){'+   
  ' $(this).css("background-color", "rgb(255, 255, 0)");'+
  '});'+
'</script>';

$('iframe').on("load",function(){
  loadedIframe = true;
  $("iframe").contents().find('script').remove();
  $("iframe").contents().find('noscript').remove();
  $("iframe").contents().find("head").append(simpleScriptTest);
  console.log('load the iframe');
});
```

Can anybody explain why this is happening and how I can resolve this?

Comment: _“in my facebook page's copy in iframe”_ – what do you mean?

Comment: @CBroe I mean that I have complete copy of facebook page to display in my iframe on same domain.

Comment: "compolete copy of fb page"? why? what for? that should not even work...

Comment: @luschn, that works (I get html, css, js and so forth, everything you get when fb page is loaded) and why is not important. It's not the issue...

Comment: the "why" is always important, because maybe there would be another (a better) way ;)

Comment: @luschn, I'm making an interface for user to be able to select elements, like <div>, <a> <button> and so on.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you call the jquery $ before loading it.
This one:

```
$('iframe').on("load",function(){
  loadedIframe = true;
  $("iframe").contents().find('script').remove();
  $("iframe").contents().find('noscript').remove();
  $("iframe").contents().find("head").append(simpleScriptTest);
  console.log('load the iframe');
});
```

The $('iframe') of jquery is called before you actually load jquery (append(simpleScriptTest)) to your page. So that's why your page does not understand $? or did you already have jquery link somewhere else?

Comment: I'm talking about a page inside iframe